# My divs are not being colored correctly

Tags: html, css

Given the following html and css I can't see why the parent is turning green and each child item is not being colored at all, or it might be that all div's including the parent and being colored green.  When I want is for the parent to remain white, the odd children (that sounds wrong) to be colored green and the even children to be colored blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    .flexParent
    {
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        -ms-flex-direction:row;
        -ms-flex-pack:start;
        -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
        border-style:dashed;
        border-color:purple;
    }

        .flexParent > div {
            -ms-flex:none;
           max-width: 50px;
           max-height: 50px;
        }

    .flexParent:nth-child(odd)
    {
        background-color:green;
    }

        .flexParent:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: blue;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flexParent">
    <div>Child1</div>
    <div>Child2</div>
    <div>Child3</div>
    <div>Child4</div>
    <div>Child5</div>
    <div>Child6</div>
    <div>Child7</div>
    <div>Child8</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) on the direct child `div` elements as oppose to the parent element.

Therefore `.flexParent:nth-child(even)`

..would be `.flexParent > div:nth-child(even)`

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/frgw7/)

```
.flexParent > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}

.flexParent > div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That worked thanks.  But why does it work? i thought nth-child means the children of the element not including the element itself.